# Cassandra SSTable for a Column Family across node

Tags: cassandra

I am running, 'nodetool cfstat' and it returns me list of Keyspace and cfstats for each column family on that node/machine. The cfstats results has, SSTable count value for each column families. My question is, Will SSTable value for column family be same across node, specially for those CF, whose SSTable count is 0? The reason is if SSTable for a column family is 0, then It is safe to drop those column families.

Answer (score 1):

The cfstats output is per node, so is only valid for the node that nodetool connected to.  To get the total SSTable count, you will need to sum them across all nodes.  A column family with no SSTables on any node is empty.

Because the counts are per node, they will be inflated by replication.  So e.g. the sum of all key counts will be approximately a factor of the replication factor higher than the actual key count.

Comment: Is there a smarter way to aggregate the results of 'nodetool cfstats' collected from all nodes. Currently, pretty much, I wrote my own tool to do that.